# The Next Palindrome SPOJ

Tags: c

I have written a brute force solution for this next palindrome problem and wanted to get Time Limit Exceeded . But when i tested a few test cases it works properly but when i submit the code in spoj i get wrong answer. Here is my code . Please can someone help me to figure out what is wrong in this program code .

```
    int main()
    {
      int t,k,cmp,tmp;
      scanf("%d",&t); //No of test cases
      while(t--)
      {
        scanf("%d",&k); //Enter the input
        while(1)
        {
          ++k;         //Increment Every no if there is no palindrome
          tmp=k;
          cmp=0;

          while(tmp%10 != 0) // Reverse a number
          {
            cmp=(cmp*10)+(tmp%10);
            tmp=tmp/10;
          }

          if(k == cmp)  // If Reverse and K are same its a palindrome .
          {
            printf("%d\n",k);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Here is the link to the problem : http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/ 
You can submit my solution at : http://www.spoj.com/submit/PALIN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (tmp%10 != 0) // Reverse a number
{
    cmp = (cmp * 10) + (tmp % 10);
    tmp = tmp / 10;
}
```

If your number has a 0 in it like 5403123 `tmp%10` is 0 and it stops reversing the number

Comment: The problem is in the input. He is taking the input as an `int` which can't hold more than 10 digits, whereas the input could be as long as 1000000 digits.

Comment: The way he takes the input is another problem but the program should work for small numbers as the input is if he corrects the erorr that I pointed. And yes, if he would store the inputs as array he would need another method to check for palindromes and the program would work for bigger numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right . I changed the code a little bit to work for your test case . It still shows wrong answer .                                       while(tmp != 0)
{
cmp=(cmp*10)+(tmp%10);
tmp=tmp/10;
}

Comment: Then the problem is the way you are storing the input. Store it as an array and then just use a `for` from 0 to `lenght/2`, and check if `first=last , second=...` and so on.

Comment: The problem was intended for you to learn storing numbers in Array and working on them. When you store it in array the whole approach will change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem says K is not more than 1000000 digits. That means k can have atmost 1000000 digits which you can't take in `int`. You will have to take the input as characters and store in an array.

`char arr[1000001];`

`int i=0, c;`

`while(c = getchar() && c!='\n') {
   arr[i] = c;
   i++;
}`

and further implement your algorithm.