# SPOJ: PALIN - The Next Palindrome: wrong output

Tags: c

Here is the code for "The Next Palindrome" which I wrote in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int check(int); //function declaration
    int t,i,k[1000],flag,n;

    scanf("%d",&t); //test cases
    for(i=0; i<t; i++)
        scanf("%d",&k[i]); //numbers

    for(i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        if(k[i]<=9999999) //Number should be of 1000000 digits
        {
            k[i]++;
            while(1)
            {
                flag=check(k[i]); //palindrome check
                if(flag==1)
                {
                    printf("%d\n",k[i]); //prints if it is palindrome and breaks
                    break;
                }
                else
                    k[i]++; //go to the next number
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int check(int n)
{
    int rn=0;
    int temp=n;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        rn=rn*10+n%10; //reversing
        n=n/10;
    }
    if(rn==temp) //number is palindrome
        return 1;
    else //number is not a palindrome
        return 0;
}
```

It is a beginner level problem from `SPOJ`.
I tried to run this code on Codeblocks and it ran fluently.
In `SPOJ`, why is it showing wrong output?

Comment: There seems to be unnecessary and possibly erroneous k[i]++ before the forever while loop. Delete that and try again.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182751/the-next-palindrome-spoj?rq=1

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho `k[i]++;` is absolutely necessary. The requirement is  "write the value of the smallest palindrome *larger than K* to output." So for input `808` output should be  `818`. The program, as is, works for small numbers and small number of inputs. But this is not what `SPOJ` wants.

Answer (score 1):

> In SPOJ, why is it showing wrong output?

This is nice solution and it works for small inputs, however it will not pass `SPOJ` for several reasons.

The requirement is:

> A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the
>   decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right
>   to left. For a given `positive integer K` of not more than `1000000`
>   digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to
>   output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.
>
> Input:
>    The first line contains integer t, the number of test cases.
>   Integers K are given in the next t lines.

So which requirements are broken in your program?

**1)** Your assumption is that only `1000` numbers will be given for processing since
you declared

```
k[1000]
```

- wrong, the number of lines is given in first line. It could be much more than `1000`. You have to dynamically assign the storage for the numbers.

**2)** 
The line

```
   if(k[i]<=9999999)
```

assumes that input is less than `9999999`
- wrong, the requirement says `positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits` which imply that much larger numbers e.g. `199999991` also have to be accepted.

**3)** The statement

> For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits

as well as warning

**Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages**

leads us to conclusion that really big numbers should be expected!

The `int` type is not a proper vehicle for storing such big numbers. The `int` will fail to hold the value if the number is bigger than `INT_MAX    +2147483647`. (Check C Library `<limits.h>`)

So, how to pass `SPOJ` challange?

***Hint:***

> One of the possible solutions - operate on strings.